# how can I execute the package

Tags: executable

I just cloned the code and finished the installation with pip in my Ubuntu. I just wonder how can I execute this package.
Here is the link: https://github.com/dshean/demcoreg

Comment: and here is the documention about the package: https://demcoreg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

Comment: That link is literally on the github page ;-)

Comment: Jos, you are right, but I'm unfamiliar with the these things, so how can this package be executed？

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package but it appears to install a number of command line utilities documented here: https://demcoreg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html.

Comment: I've made it, the reason is the command changed now like my comment to Giorgos. Thank you, Jos.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the package you can run any of the containing utilities (https://demcoreg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html) by just opening a terminal typing the tool you want + the needed arguments

ex.

```
apply_dem_translation [-h] [-outdir OUTDIR] dem_fn log_fn
```

Comment: I get this worked. The command has been changed to "apply_dem_translation.py", and the useage also changed.

Comment: Nicee. If you found helpful my answer it would be grateful marking it 